# How do you get pyqtSignal to properly emit a signal that the rpyc service has been turned on?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, data-collection, rpyc

I have two widgets that are in two separate python files. They are:
A) temperature_service: acts as the rpyc service that turns off and on the service and encodes the instructions for the tasks my various clients want to carry out.
B) temperature of B: acts as the client that connects to the service and asks for the temperatures every 10 seconds.

My issue is that I cannot get my client to only start asking for temperatures after the service has been turned on via the pushbutton 'Connect'. I want to do it such that when the button connect is clicked, this sends a signal to the client that the service is 'ON' and that the client can now ask for temperature values.

The service widget:

```
class StartServerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, temp_service):
        super().__init__()
        self.temp_service = temp_service
        
    def run(self):
        self.temp_service.start_server()

class StopServerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, temp_service):
        super().__init__()
        self.temp_service = temp_service

    def run(self):
        self.temp_service.stop_server()


class Ui_temp_serv(QObject):
    start_collection_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thread = None
        self.temp_service = TemperatureService()
        self.server_running = False

    def setupUi(self, temp_serv):
    # Connect the "CONNECT"/"DISCONNECT" button to start/end the server
        self.temp_service_conn.clicked.connect(self.start_server_thread)
        self.temp_service_disconn.clicked.connect(self.stop_server_thread)


  def start_server_thread(self):
        if self.thread and self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()  # Terminate the previous thread if still running
        self.thread = StartServerThread(self.temp_service)
        self.thread.start()
        self.server_running = True
        self.start_collection_signal.emit()

    def stop_server_thread(self):
        if self.thread and self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()  # Terminate the previous thread if still running
        self.thread = StopServerThread(self.temp_service)
        self.thread.start()
        self.server_running = False
```

The temperature client:

```
from temperature_service import Ui_temp_serv

class TemperatureAClient:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def get_temperature(self):
        return self.connection.temperature_service.exposed_get_temperature()

class Ui_temp_B(object):
    def setupUi(self, temp_B):
     self.ui_temp_serv = Ui_temp_serv()
        self.ui_temp_serv.start_collection_signal.connect(self.start_data_collection)
        self.timer = QTimer(temp_B)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.collect_values)
        self.interval = 10000

def start_data_collection(self):
        if not self.ui_temp_serv.server_running:
            print("Server is not running. Cannot collect data")
        self.collect_values()
        self.timer.start(self.interval)

    def collect_values(self):
        connection = Temp_Connection()
        client = TemperatureAClient(connection)
        _, _, round_2 = client.get_temperature()

        if round_2:
            for entry in round_2:
                mean_value =  round(entry['mean'], 3)
                min_value = round(entry['min'], 3)
                max_value = round(entry['max'], 3)

                self.B_mean_temp.setText(str(mean_value))
                self.B_min_temp.setText(str(min_value))
                self.B_max_temp.setText(str(max_value))
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                self.B_timestamp.setText(timestamp)
        else:
            print("Round 2 statistics list is empty.")
```

What I have done above gives me the following issue: when I have both widgets open and click the CONNECT button, the service says 'Server started successfully' but then nothing happens. No measurements are taken and nothing is updated on the client.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre]. Also be aware that editing or "merging" pyuic generated files is considered bad practice and can result in unexpected behavior (which should be guessed by the clear warning on top of those files). Do follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).